# Sequentially Execute Php sripts in batch file only after execution of one is completed

Tags: php, batch-file

I have a requirement where I have multiple php scripts to be executed and one php script depends on the result of previous script. Note that all of these scripts update MySQL database.
Can anyone tell me tools or commands for this purpose?
Thank you!

This is the code in my jobs.bat file

`path to php directory\php.exe  path to php scritps\script 1.php
 path to php directory\php.exe  path to php scritps\script 2.php`

I just want to know whether command 2 will wait for the "script 1" until is completely executed and updated the database OR both the commands will execute sequentially in parallel?

Comment: Huh? Run the one that must be run first first and run the others afterwards. What's the problem?

Comment: When I run first script the next batch command does not wait for the completion of first php script.

Comment: Show us what you have got so far then please.

Comment: Sequentially and parallel are opposites! Sequentially means one after the other in SEQUENCE. Parallel means at the same time and overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be a little more specific about what kind of data needs to be passed from one php script to another.

A bash script would work just fine to execute the php scripts sequentially:

```
php /path/to/script1.php
php /path/to/script2.php
php /path/to/script3.php
```

As for the passing of data from one php script to another, you have several options.  One of them is packing all the variables you need to pass into an array, serializing it, then outputting it to a file.  When the next script starts, the first thing you would do is access the file, unserialize the array, then use the data it contains in your script.

First php script:

```
// code that does stuff
...

// this comes at the end of your script
// example of variables that you might want to send to the next script
$some_var = 4;
$some_string = 'It works for strings too.';
$some_array = array('red' => '#ff0000', 'green' => '#00ff00', 'blue' => '#0000ff');

// bundle the variables into an array
$bundled_data = array([0] => $var, [1] => $some_string, [2] => $some_array);

// serialize the array into a string
$serialized_array = serialize($bundled_data);

// then write to the file
$file = fopen('temp.txt', 'w');
$file.write($serialized_array);
$file.close();
```

Second php script:

```
// this comes at the beginning of your script
// retrieve the saved data
$file_text = file_get_contents('/path/to/temp.txt');
$bundled_data = unserialize($file_text);

// access the data and use it in your script
$var = $bundled_data[0];
$some_string = $bundled_data[1];
$some_array = $bundled_data[2];
```

Hopefully this answer is relevant to your situation.  In the future, please post code examples, and explain what you have tried.

Comment: I appreciate your action, but My Question is about the sequence of execution, I just wanted to know whether the execution of second script occurs only after the first script is done executing or all the scripts called in a batch file execute one after another in a batch like environment?

Comment: Yes, the first script will finish before the second one begins.

Comment: Thank You! May you get more and more success in reward for helping people :)